# Preprocessor inconsistencies in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

I'm compiling the following C++ code in Visual Studio 2015 (update 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

////////////////////////////////////////

#define UNDERSCORE1(a,b) a ## _ ## b
#define UNDERSCORE(a,b) UNDERSCORE1(a,b)

#define STRINGIFY1(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY1(x)

#define VALUE(x) UNDERSCORE(x, VALUE)
#define NEXT(x) (VALUE(x) + 1)

/////////////////////////////////////////

#define X1_VALUE 0
#define X2_VALUE NEXT(X1)
#define X3_VALUE NEXT(X2)
#define TOTAL NEXT(X3)

int main() {
    cout << STRINGIFY(TOTAL) << endl;
    cout << TOTAL << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result printed to stdout is very strange:

```
(X3_VALUE + 1)
3
```

When trying the same on gcc, build fails (expectedly).
When commenting out `cout << TOTAL << endl;` I get [something different](https://www.ideone.com/wORFpq) altogether:

```
(NEXT(X2) + 1)
```

---

Actually gcc behavior makes sense, since `NEXT` macro is called recursively: `NEXT(X3)` is expanded to `X3_VALUE` which in turn expands to `NEXT(X2)`, so the second expansion of `NEXT` macro (`NEXT(X2)`) is not performed.

What doesn't make sense is Visual Studio behavior:

- When printing the macro `TOTAL` using `STRINGIFY`, `NEXT` seems to be expanded **twice** to yield `X3_VALUE`.
- When compiling the macro `TOTAL` directly to send it to `cout`, `NEXT` is expanded all the way! As if the preprocessor ran multiple times to recursively expand `NEXT`.

Another thing I tried was to compile this code in Visual Studio with the `/P` compiler option, to get the preprocessed code:

```
int main() {
    cout << "(X3_VALUE + 1)" << endl;
    cout << (((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

- So is it, as I suspect, a bug in Visual Studio preprocessor? Or a legit undefined behavior?
- Perhaps this behavior can be abused to truly expand macros recursively? I know that a limited recursion [is possible with some tricks](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/Is-the-C-preprocessor-Turing-complete%3F) but is limited to a predefined number of scans. In this case I did not observe a limit to the number of times `NEXT` is expanded.

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_UNDERSCORE`, `_STRINGIFY`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: I would start by avoiding reserved identifiers. `_` followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for **any use**.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'll change the question to avoid underscore followed by a capital letter. The problem remains the same.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line. Oh, and get rid of `using namespace std;`. Sooner or later it will bite you.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/07/06/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/

Comment: @PeteBecker This is not relevant to my question at all. I agree about the endl, regarding `using namespace std`, I avoid it in header files, but using it in cpp files is usually considered ok.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for this link! I did not know how many issues exist with the MSVC preprocessor. Looking at the "behavior changes" they specify, I couldn't find anything that directly explains what I see here.

Comment: @AmirGonnen -- re: "This is not relevant to my question at all." Indeed. That's why I started with "This doesn't address the question, but ..." And, no, `using namespace std;` in cpp files is **not** "usually considered ok." Sooner or later it will bite you.

Comment: It is behavior #6.  This goes back to about 1983, long before C89 nailed down the expected behavior.   Early K&R preprocessors were inconsistent about it, they gambled wrong.  Possibly helped by it having to be able to run in 96KB of RAM.  They decided to not break the codebase of existing customers, a notorious affliction Microsoft suffers from, that has been changing of late.  Tagging a question like this with [visual-c++] is usually a good way to avoid irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans mentioned in the comments, the MSVC preprocessor is not conformant.

You can enable the conformant preprocessor with `-experimental:preprocessor`.

Here is a simplified repro + solution: https://godbolt.org/z/7u_-bH

Comment: As Hans explained very well in the comments, this is indeed an MSVC non-conformant behavior. You suggested a way to prevent it using the `-experimental:preprocessor`, However, this was not my question. My questions were 1) **Is it a bug in MSVC?** (yes, as Hans explained) 2) **Can this behavior be abused to truly expand macros recursively?** (to this question I got no answer yet, perhaps the answer is No).

Comment: AFAIR it does not expand macros recursively. It only does 2 passes.

Comment: If it does only 2 passes, how does it come with the result `3` as the expansion of `TOTAL` in my example above? As I see it, `NEXT` would have to be expanded recursively 3 times.